# Accessing nested Inbox folders in Outlook with Python

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

I am trying to use Python to get attachments stored in an Outlook subfolder nested inside my Inbox.
Let's call the folder that I want to access "TargetFolder," and each sub-level "Sub Folder 1","Sub Folder 2", etc.
I can get it to work, but I am not sure that my code is very efficient since I have to declare each folder each time I go deeper into the subfolders - therefore I would appreciate a more efficient approach.

Currently, my code looks as follows:

```
import win32com.client as client   # import the library for interacting with Outlook

outlook = client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)  # Default OlDefaultFolders enumeration for "Inbox" (Outlook)

Subfolder1_folder = inbox.Folders["Sub Folder 1"]              # First Level
Subfolder2_folder = Subfolder1_folder.Folders["Sub Folder 2"]  # Second Level
Subfolder3_folder = Subfolder2_folder.Folders["Sub Folder 3"]  # Third Level
Subfolder4_folder = Subfolder3_folder.Folders["Sub Folder 4"]  # Fourth Level
TargetFolder = Subfolder4_folder.Folders["Target Folder"]      # Target Level
```

Is there a way to write a better code? I tried writing something like "Sub Folder 1/Sub Folder 2"... but I get errors

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any other way of getting sub-folders. You need to deal with the `Folders` property anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't have to declare separate variables - you can continue reusing the same variable. Secondly, you can create a function that takes a Folder object and a path (string). It can extract the folder name from the path, and if there is still path to process, remove the name of the current folder and call itself with the child folder and the remaining path.